# jQuery autocomplete getting the error

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to implement jQuery autocompletion.
I am importing jQuery files in my project and using them in my JSP:

```
 <script src="JQUERY/development-bundle/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="JQUERY/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script src="JQUERY/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="JQUERY/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
        <script src="JQUERY/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js"></script>
        <script src="JQUERY/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/employeeAutocomplete.js"></script>
```

Here I have written one input box in JSP file, through JSP I am calling the JS file:

```
<input type="text" id="empauto" class="searchbox">
```

Here I am calling one JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       

 $('#empauto').autocomplete({
          source: function(request,response ){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "empauto.do?method=getAutoEmpdetails",
                    //dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
    //                  alert(data.list1[0].empname);
                        response( $.map( data.list1, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.empname,
                                value: item.empname,
                                id : item.email+"("+item.phone+"("+item.shiftname+"("+item.deptname+"("+item.emplocation+"("+item.empid
                            }
                        }));
                    }

                });
            },

      });


    });
```

When I call the autocomplete method, I'm getting the following error:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'
```

This error will be coming before the source: function(request,response )

Comment: Try `dataType: "jsonp"`

Comment: within __$.ajax__ set __dataType: "json"__

Comment: @Pranav c,@Tomanow am tried both ways its not working

Comment: Make sure jQuery and jQuery-UI are loading properly

Comment: everything loaded properly

Comment: Try calling autocomplete without the function, i.e. do `autocomplete()` or `autocomplete({})`.

Comment: Is the `<input>` created dynamically?

Comment: alert the respose data.... and check the structure......plz provide the response data structure if u can

Comment: which version of Jquery ui are you using ??

Comment: @JNF thanks for the answer with out ready function its working fine but not hit the action class

Answer (score 0):

Can you refer this: [Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858331/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-autocomplete)

Generally this happens when we have more than 1 version of jQuery.

Note: was not able to add this into comments since comments addition needs more than 50 points

Comment: your suggetion is good but here am import only one version see the above code.please give me another solution if you Know